# Tomcat server needs restart to fetch updated Neo4J database

Tags: java, web-services, neo4j, tomcat8, application-restart

I use Apache **Tomcat** as my web server. I have a RESTful web service which fetches data from a Neo4J graph database. The **Neo4J** graph database gets updated periodically. Unless i restart the tomcat server, my web service doesn't fetch the new results. Hence, i need to restart the tomcat server after every successful build of Neo4J graph, (which i don't think is a good practice).

Need help on this.

[EDIT]

So, my web service has reads Neo4J folder from the path which is defined in a properties file.

```
NEO4J_PATH = /home/user/databases/GraphDB/Neo4Jdb
```

My Tomcat is installed in `/home/user/softwares/tomcat`

My Web service code is kept in `/home/user/software/tomcat/webapps/webservice`

Everyday, my Neo4Jdb gets updated. When i do the web service call without restarting the tomcat server, the new results don't appear. It is only after i restart the server, new results get displayed.

Comment: What driver are you using for Neo4j?

Comment: @Gabriel I'm using Neo4J java driver.

Comment: Seems like something else is going on, as it makes no sense to need to reset the database to retrieve latest values. Maybe something's cached? Maybe some details are missing from the question?

Comment: @DavidMakogon i edited the question. Can you check and tell if this is clear? I often do cache refresh but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your application running in Tomcat uses an [embedded Neo4j instance](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/3.0/#tutorials-java-embedded), but the directory with the graph data is updated by another process? That's a recipe for disaster (or at least significant runtime breakage).

Neo4j is a (graph) database **management** system, it's supposed to manage its data: any modification should happen through it while it's running.

I see 2 ways here:

- have the application expose an API to update the data
- have the application stop the embedded instance (though an API) before updating the directory, then start a new instance

Comment: Yes you're right that the war file that is deployed in TC webapps uses `embedded Neo4J instance` after the directory is build by an another process. Can you explain a bit more on the above two ways suggested by you, especially the 2nd one. How can i make sure that i do not need to restart the tomcat every time?

Comment: To avoid restarting the Tomcat, it needs to restart the embedded Neo4j instance and it needs to know when to do that, hence the API I mentioned. It can be an HTTP endpoint, a JMX MBean exposing operations, a message queue, whatever. Or it could even be a scheduled action (everyday at 5:00).